# Which Debugger is to be used to debug elf file generated by arm-none-linux-gnueabi compiler

Tags: debugging, assembly, arm

I used **arm-none-linux-gnueabi** compiler to compile my assembly code.

Which debugger should be used to debug my code in windows

Comment: `qemu` and `gdb` (with any frontend) should work, if not the most conveniently.

Comment: writing to the serial port or jtag connection.

Comment: You may run [`gdbserver`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gdbserver) on the ARM target and use a *cross-gdb* on the Windows host.  You need a shadow filesystem on the PC, so that the *cross-gdb* can access it for *symbols*.  This is probably the *best case* as you actually debug on the target, but probably the most difficult to setup.

Answer (score 0):

You need an execution environment in which your code can run. Your choice of debugger is limited by that. Your best choice here may be *gdb*.

Since you cross-compiled for the ARM architecture, your choices are ARM hardware or an ARM emulator (such as qemu).

If your code is running as the operating system, you need a JTAG probe if you are working with hardware, or debugger support in the emulator.

If your code is a regular process, use *gdb* on the host machine, and *gdbserver* on the target machine.

Comment: I just want an emulator, then which one do you suggest qemu or gdb ?

Comment: You need both. *qemu* is responsible for executing the code (which you would need even when not debugging), while *gdb* provides the debugging user interface and interprets the debug information generated during compilation. You will also need a *gdbserver* compiled for ARM, running inside the virtual machine.